# How to redirect an incoming request to specific serverName to different server in apache2?

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I've been playing with the `http-vhost.conf` file in apache2 in order to achieve the following:

I got two domains:

```
domain1.co.uk (app to be hosted by apache2 on port 80)

domain2.com   (app to be hosted by glassfish on port 8080)
```

I have configured the DNS on both domains to point to the same location.

This is the content of my `http-vhost.conf` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://domain2.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://domain2.com:8080/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName www.domain1.co.uk
    ServerAlias domain1.co.uk
  # ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
   # CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that, if I put `domain2.com` in my browser, I reach `domain1.co.uk` app.

Please help!

Comment: And if you use '\*:80' instead of just '\*' in the first VirtualHost, and drop the NameVirtualHost for '\*' as well?

Comment: Hi @GrahamDumpleton! Yes! It works now!! Simply by removing the NameVirtualHost and using the *:80 instead of simply *. Thank you so much! How can I mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Even though the solution worked fine, I wonder if I have anything wrong that might be causing the following issue: